# How do I convert a non ruby on rails date into a readable format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there anyway in ruby on rails to convert this date `2014-08-13T22:11:18.138Z` into a more readable format such as dd/mm/yyyy or jan 1st 2014.

It's from a createdAt field of a parse.com database.

How do I convert this?

Would I need some type of regex?

Is there built in ruby code I can use to do the conversion for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do with:

```
// it will be parsed to the datetime in the timezone configured by rails app.
Time.zone.parse('2014-08-13T22:11:18.138Z').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class has a whole lot of built in conversions for standard formats. Identify the format ( in this case RFC3339 ) and you will be able to find something like this:

```
require 'date'
return Date.rfc3339('2014-08-13T22:11:18.138Z')
 #<Date: 2014-08-13 ((2456883j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your locale en.yml

```
date:
    formats:
      # Use the strftime parameters for formats.
      # When no format has been given, it uses default.
      # You can provide other formats here if you like!
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

in your view

```
<%= I18n.l @entry.created_at, :format => :short %>
```